# RMAN archive logs not deleted

Tags: rman

I am working on an Oracle11gR2 database. The database is in DataGuard mode, even though the dataguard is set to DEFER.

I want to delete all archive logs that have been backed up at least 2 times to tape.

```
rman> list archivelog all backed up 2 times to device type sbt_tape;
```

shows a list of archive logs that match the criteria

However, when I later try to run

```
rman> delete force noprompt archivelog all backed up 2 times to device type sbt_tape;
```

no files are deleted.

All parameters are set to default values, apart from retention policy which is set to a window of 370 days

A look into the trace I generated, shows, among other things, this message for each of the files that were reported by the `list` command

```
DBGMISC: Matching archived log has 0 backups
```

which I do not know how to interpret.

Any ideas on how to further investigate the issue would be greatly appreciated

rman configuration is as follows

```
using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name ORACLE are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 370 DAYS;
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE 'SBT_TAPE' PARMS  'SBT_LIBRARY=/opt/tivoli/tsm/client/oracle/bin64/libobk.so';
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '+ASMARCHIVES/oracle/snap_orcld.f';
```

Comment: Can you show the rman configuration? ‘Show all;’

Comment: Added configuration in post. Thanks!

Comment: what is the output from "list archivelog all backed up 2 times to device type disk;"?

Comment: None, we backup directly to tape

Comment: I guess you get an error message like 'more backups needed'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE TO 1; # default
the database wants to make sure backups are made to tape and to disk. If you want it different because you only backup to tape that remove the lines about the disk backups.

```
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK CLEAR;
```

you also could consider setting the ARCHIVELOG deletion policy.